# Express/Node/Mongoose: Why does find() on collection fail in my router.js?

Tags: express, mongoose

When I try to do a "find" or "findOne on my Mongo collection (using ExpressJS/Mongoose), I get an error: 
"TypeError: _Cardsets.Cardset.find(...).forEach is not a function"
(Notice the doubling of the name of the collection, which is named 'cardsets' (lowercase and plural) on the database.

from app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import cookeParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import ejs from 'ejs';
import expressValidator from 'express-validator';
import flash from 'connect-flash';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import index from './routes/index';
import users from './routes/users';
import mysets from './routes/mysets';
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;

[...]

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/CRMDB', {
    useMongoClient: true
});
let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("fail--->" + error);
});
db.on("open", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

[...]

app.use('/mysets/',mysets);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

from ./models/Cardsets.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CardsetSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    setTitle: String,
    minScore: Number,
    [...]
    dateModified: Date,
    results: Array
});

export const Cardset = mongoose.model('Cardset', CardsetSchema);
```

from ./routes/mysets.js

```
import express from 'express';
let router =  express.Router();
import { Cardset } from '../models/Cardsets';

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var id = req.user._id;
    var dataset = [];
    Cardset.find({creator: id}).forEach(function(myDoc) {
       var tempData = {};
       tempData.setTitle = myDoc.setTitle;
       tempData._id = myDoc._id;
       tempData.language = myDoc.language;
       tempData.dateCreated = myDoc.dateCreated;
       dataset.push(tempData);
       });
       console.log("dataset = "+dataset);
    res.render('pages/mysets', {
       dataset: dataset
    });
});
export default router;
```

I was hoping to be able to pass a data object created from the mongo documents to the client page.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` - Have you tried console logging `Cardset` to ensure it's a valid array?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but you are setting module.exports and then calling export right after in your ` ./models/Cardsets.js` file. Normally you do one or the other.

Comment: I removed one of the redundancies, and now the Cardset object is being exported, but now the error message is different. I updated the question to reflect the new error message.

Comment: I think find() returns a Promise and you're expecting it to be an array, that's why it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should be using a **promise** in your code as below:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var id = req.user._id;
    var dataset = [];

    Cardset.find({creator: id}).then((Docs) => {
       Docs.forEach((myDoc) => {
           var tempData = {};
           tempData.setTitle = myDoc.setTitle;
           tempData._id = myDoc._id;
           tempData.language = myDoc.language;
           tempData.dateCreated = myDoc.dateCreated;
           dataset.push(tempData);
       });
    });

    console.log("dataset = "+dataset);

    res.render('pages/mysets', {
    dataset: dataset
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked! You might want to fix an error that you brought over from my code (which I fixed on the post). Line 7 should say "var tempData = {}". I had left out the declaration, which caused an error. Thanks for the help, I'm embarrassed to say how many hours I spent on this!

Comment: Good to hear that this helped you. Also, I had updated my answer.